# Does plasma beam focus itself at sufficient velocity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, plasma-physics

Imagine a beam of positively charged moving particles as shown in first image (the anode is only illustrative):

[image: Image 1. : view from side]

Then take a look at the cross section of such beam in the second image:

[image: Image 2. : cross section]

I imagine that this stream could be thought of as a current carrying wire. It should then induce a circular magnetic field perpendicular to the particles' motion. Furthermore, the magnetic field should be the strongest at the edges of the beam. Then due to Lorentz force and the left hand rule the particles should experience inward facing radial force.

As the beam of equally charged particles would repel each other due to Coulombs force (and probably pressure) it would also produce outward facing radial force.

The question is: is there a speed at which both of these radial forces cancel each other? Or am I missing something? Maybe there are some oscillations happening?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinch_(plasma_physics)

Comment: Oh, wow! I had no idea that this effect could be so strong to even support nuclear fusion

Comment: This setup is very unstable to what are called beam or streaming instabilities.  It will not last long.